# Formula to calculate the 5th [day of the week] when applicable

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date

I've used the following formula to get the nth xday of the month:

```
=DATE(B2,A2,1+7*n)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-xday))
```

where year is in B2 and month (as a number from 1 to 12) is in A2, and where `xday` is a number representing the day of the week (1 = Sun through to 7 = Sat), so for 1st Saturday that becomes:

```
=DATE(B2,A2,1+7*1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-7))
```

Now, this works for months with 4 weeks. How can I modify this formula to calculate when a month has 5 weeks?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and ugly solution, you could say

```
=IF(MONTH(DATE($B$2,$A$2,1+7*n)-WEEKDAY(DATE($B$2,$A$2,8-xday))) = $A$2,
          DATE($B$2,$A$2,1+7*n)-WEEKDAY(DATE($B$2,$A$2,8-xday)),
          "Non-existent date")
```

I.e., if the date calculated by your formula is in the correct month, use it.  If you have overflowed into the first week of the following month, then don’t use it.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I can't chance the overflow into the next month. but thanks for answering :-)

Comment: I think Scott's solution does the same as mine. If there's no 5th Monday or whatever then you get "Non-existent date".....

Comment: @Leila: “I can’t chance the overflow into the next month, but thanks for answering. :-)”  What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

`=(B2&"-"&A2&"-"&1+7*n-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-xday)))+0`

That does effectively the same as your original except it builds the date as a text string, e.g. for 5th Tuesday in October 2012 it will create this text string

2012-10-30

....then the +0 at the end co-erces that string to a date, 30-Oct-2012. But if there is no 5th xday then the string created is not a valid date, e.g. for 5th Saturday in October you'd get 2012-10-34. Clearly that isn't a valid date so when you add zero the coercion doesn't work and you get #VALUE! error. If you prefer a text message instead then just use IFERROR, something like this

`=IFERROR((B2&"-"&A2&"-"&1+7*n-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-xday)))+0,"No 5th day")`

Comment: Barry, this is just what I needed. Thank you so much!!! :-)